# Call a constructor defined in header but implemented in cpp

Tags: c++

I want to create an object of class `SetHinzufuegen` and give it a ListBox as parameter. It should be used this way: I have another class that has a member `ListBox A`. I create an object of class `SetHinzufuegen` with this `ListBox A`as parameter so I can edit `A` from there. 
How do I call the constructor?
Moreover, my class inherits from Dialog with `#include <Dialog.h>` and uses the resource GUI.dll with its dialog `DS_Window`.

GUI.h:

```
class SetHinzufuegen():public Dialog
{
public:
    SetHinzufuegen(ListBox);
    ListBox setWithVariablesListInputToWrite;
```

GUI.cpp:

```
SetHinzufuegen::SetHinzufuegen(setWithVariablesListInput):Dialog(DS_Window, "GUI");
{
    InputToEdit = setWithVariablesListInput;
    InitMsgMap();
}
```

I get a syntax error in the declaration of the constructor's function, because I don't understand the concept here.

This way, with declaration and implementation in one class, it works:

```
class SetHinzufuegen : public Dialog
    {
    public:
        SetHinzufuegen(ListBox setWithVariablesListInput) : Dialog(DS_Window, "GUI")
        {
            inputToEdit = setWithVariablesListInput;
            InitMsgMap();
        }

        ListBox setWithVariablesListInputToWrite;
```

Here I call the constructor with

```
SetHinzufuegen SetDlg(setWithVariablesList);
```

What do I need to change in my header declaration or cpp implementation?

Comment: Nitpicking: Your constructor is not defined in the header - it's _declared_. It's _defined_ in the .cpp module.

Comment: Ok still getting used to the naming. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the constructor parameter type, and have a spurious `;`. You need

```
SetHinzufuegen::SetHinzufuegen(ListBox setWithVariablesListInput) 
: Dialog(DS_Window, "GUI")
{
    InputToEdit = setWithVariablesListInput;
    InitMsgMap();
}
```

Note that you don't necessarily want to copy the `ListBox`. If you don't, then use a `const` reference parameter.

Comment: The error remains... (Note: I have defined the `setWithVariablesListInput` as of type `ListBox` some lines before, so I would not need to name its type in the constructor, right?) The copy itself is really not the best idea, but I did not want to make it even more complicated, and copying worked for the 3rd code example. 
I don't understand this error...

Comment: @user2366975 When I said "You are missing the constructor parameter type" I meant it. Anyway, you should post a minimal code sample that reproduces your problem, and state what error you are getting.

Comment: How can I post a working example if I use my own resource file?

Comment: I think the addtional reason that kept it from working are those 2 brackets in `class SetHinzufuegen():public Dialog`. If I remove them, the compiler stops at at a different code line. thx